# Concurrently node exits with status 1. This halts Teamcity leading it to believe that the tests failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner, json-server

I am trying to run two scripts at once with `concurrently`. The basic command looks something like this:

```
concurrently -k --success first "node ./tools/mock-webapi/mock-webapi.js" "npm run test-single-run"
```

Which in turn calls (local):

```
"test-single-run": "karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless"
```

Or on remote (teamcity host):

```
"test-teamcity": "karma start --reporters teamcity --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless",
```

The tests run just fine (local & remote). However, I keep getting exit code 1. Even if I use `concurrently -k --success first` I still get a `code 1` even with `--success first`.

```
[1] 09 05 2018 17:56:54.032:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
[1] npm run test-single-run exited with code 0
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[0] node ./tools/mock-webapi/mock-webapi.js exited with code 1
```

I tried various ways for `json-server` to gracefully receive this signal. Nothing seems to work.

**mock-webapi.js**

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function (code) {
    console.log('Handle SIGTERM', process.pid, code);
    exitCode = 0;
    server.close(function () {
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

process.on('SIGKILL', function (code) {
    console.log('SIGKILL received...', code);
    exitCode = 0;
    server.close(function () {
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

process.on('SIGINT', function (code) {
    console.log('SIGINT received...', code);
    exitCode = 0;
    server.close(function () {
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution to this problem. I wrote a little script that runs the mock webapi and the karma tests as child processes.

**test-single-run-single-process.js**

```
const spawn = require('cross-spawn');

/**
 * Running the tests requires a mock webapi which is gladly provided by json-server.
 * Running the tests in teamcity requires that everything is executed from one terminal.
 * Different mock data sets can be easily used if the mockapi is a child process.
 * We do not need to keep the mockWebapi alive between trials.
 * 
 * After all the tests have succeeded we then close the json-server by sending (SIGINT).
 * Finally the process will exit with code 0, which means for TeamCity that all is OK.
 * Now it can proceed with the next build step.
 * So basically we can run the tests both standalone and in one single terminal.
 * Notice that the mockWebapi is a forked process so we can send messages to it.
 * 
 * <!> Failed approach - Closing the mockwebapi
 * Using kill command leaves no option for gracefull shutdown. 
 * SIGINT or SIGTERM signals are not received by the mockWebapi.
 * The server will stay active keeping the 3000 port busy.
 * 
 *     mockWebapi.kill('SIGINT'); 
 */

const fork = require('child_process').fork
const mockWebapi = fork('./tools/mock-webapi/mock-webapi.js')

const karma = spawn(
    `karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless`,
    [], { stdio: 'inherit' }
);

// 1) Listen to karma exit
karma.on('close', (code, signal) => { 
    console.log('Karma closed. Code:', code, 'Signal:', signal);
    code === 0 && gracefullyCloseMockWebapi(true);
});
karma.on('error', (code, signal) => { 
    console.log('Karma error. Code:', code, 'Signal:', signal);
    gracefullyCloseMockWebapi(false);
});

let gracefullyCloseMockWebapi = (testsCompletedOk) => {
    console.log('Gracefuly close webapi. Tests completed ok:', testsCompletedOk);
    mockWebapi.send({ testsCompletedOk });
};

// 2) Finish the job, pass the exit code from mockWeabpi to the command line
mockWebapi.on('close', (code, signal) => { 
    console.log('Mock webapi closed. Code:', code, 'Signal:', signal);
    process.exit(code);
});
```

**mock-webapi.js**

```
// Some project specific work is done before starting the server

/**
 * <!> Failed approach - concurrently
 * Dispatching the following command will exit with code 1. 
 * The SIGTERM or SIGINT handlers are not called after the tests are done.
 * concurrently --kill-others --success first 
 *     "node ./tools/mock-webapi/mock-webapi.js" "npm run test-single-run"
 *
 *     process.on('SIGINT', (code) => {
 *         server.close(function () {
 *             process.exit(0);
 *         });
 *     });
 *
 * <!> Working approach
 * Spawning a process child and sending it a message to self-close.
 * Double check it with "echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%" after the processes terminated.
 */

function setupJsonServer(mocks, routes) {
    let server = jsonServer.create(),
        port = 3000;

    const router = jsonServer.router(mocks);

    server.use(jsonServer.defaults());
    server.use(jsonServer.rewriter(routes));
    server.use(router);

    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`JSON Server is running at ${port}`)
        console.log('Process id is', process.pid);
    });

    process.on('message', function ({ testsCompletedOk }) {
        console.log('Mockwebapi will terminate. Tests completed ok', testsCompletedOk)
        process.exit(testsCompletedOk === true ? 0 : 1)
    });

}
```

Additional reading:

- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a
- https://github.com/moxystudio/node-cross-spawn
- https://medium.com/@NorbertdeLangen/communicating-between-nodejs-processes-4e68be42b917
- [node.js child process - difference between spawn & fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861362/node-js-child-process-difference-between-spawn-fork)
- [Pass large array to node child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052913/pass-large-array-to-node-child-process)
- https://azimi.me/2014/12/31/kill-child_process-node-js.html
- [How to kill all child processes on exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833047/how-to-kill-all-child-processes-on-exit)
- [kill all child_process when node process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275809/kill-all-child-process-when-node-process-is-killed)
- [Communicating between two different processes in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213501/communicating-between-two-different-processes-in-node-js)